# в Odoo 16 немогу подключить кадровый hr.employee для выбора

Tags: odoo

хочу создать таблицу (строку) с которого можно выбрать ответственного сотрудника
(Не судите строго я только начинающий)

```
responsible_person = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Responsible Persons', widget='many2many_tags')
```

а вид

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="tmz.list_tmz_movements_history">
    <field name="name">tmz movements history</field>
    <field name="model">tmz.tmz_movements_history</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree> 
        <field name="responsible_person"/>
      </tree>
    </field>
  </record>
```

вы дает ошибку

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.